# More elegant way to duplicate tensor along axis

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to duplicate one layer of my batch of images to the other 3.
The following code works, but I would like to ask about a more elegant way of doing this:

```
output = tf.stack([input[:,:,:,0], input[:,:,:,0], input[:,:,:,0]], axis=3)
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.tile` for that.

```
arrayToStack = input[:,:,:,0]
shape = list(arrayToStack.shape)+[1]
output = tf.tile(arrayToStack.reshape(shape), [1,1,1,3])
```